# VS Code Syntax Highlighting Delay

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a setting in VS code that changes how fast error lines show up. When I start typing, the text is immediately highlighted red. Is there a setting to change this behavior?

Comment: Related (if you want toggle/disable rather than debounce/delay): [How can I easily toggle display of problem underlining in VS Code editor panels?](/q/74753185)